# How to read large data of about 50GB file (CSV,txt) on computer with 16GB RAM without GPU

Tags: python-3.x

As Pandas does not support to load data of size larger than the Primary memory(RAM) of machine. I have tried various python packages such as Koalas, Dask, Modin, Vaex but are not working as given in their documentations.

I have not used chunking method as we cannot identify the Outliers or calculate Mean, Mode, other statistics using such chunks of data.

Koalas reads full data but Mode, some other options are missing, while Dask is lazy loading and we cannot get the above stats on full data.

Any suggestions to get this issue resolved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely can calculate mean easily on chunked data. Just take average of mean of each chunk. Now median might be trickier.

Comment: AFAIK, [memory mapping](https://realpython.com/python-mmap/) allows one to deal with files that don't fit into memory